# error: reduction variable ‘v1’ is private in outer context

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have the following Fortran code

```
program hello

    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    
    integer :: num_threads = 2
    
    print*, "Display Hello world!"
    print*, "Number of threads used = ", num_threads
    
    call loop()
    
end program hello


subroutine loop()
    integer :: i,j,k,n
    real :: c0
    real, allocatable :: v1(:,:)

    n = 3
    c0 = 0.
    if (.not. allocated (v1)) allocate(v1(n,n))    
    v1 = c0
    
    !$omp do private(i, j, k) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+: v1)    
    do i = 1, n 
      do j = 1, n
        do k = 1, n
          v1(i,j) = v1(i,j) + k
        end do
        write (*,*) i, j, v1(i,j)
      end do
    end do  
    !$omp end do   

end subroutine
```

gfotran -fopenmp leads to

```
error: reduction variable ‘v1’ is private in outer context
     !$omp do private(i, j, k) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+: v1)
```

I checked [reduction variable is private in outer context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253691/reduction-variable-is-private-in-outer-context)
but still unsure the reason for my issue. `v1` is only used inside the loop.

What's the reason for the error message `reduction variable ‘v1’ is private in outer context` ?

[Solved, by adding  `!$omp parallel` and  `!$omp end parallel`]

Comment: This is similar to, but not quite the same as, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347944/fortran-openmp-with-subroutines-and-functions/35361665#35361665 The info there will answer your question though.

Comment: Also note this will not parallelise your loop - you have no parallel region in the above code, and without that it will all be single threaded.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding ``` !$omp parallel``` and ```!$omp end parallel``` works!!

Comment: @AlphaF20 Hi considering providing the solution has an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Ian Bush's comment. By adding `!$omp parallel` and `!$omp end parallel`, i.e.,

```
program hello

    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    
    integer :: num_threads = 2
    
    print*, "Display Hello world!"
    print*, "Number of threads used = ", num_threads
          
    call loop()
    
end program hello


subroutine loop()
    integer :: i,j,k,n
    real :: c0
    real, allocatable :: v1(:,:)

    n = 3
    c0 = 0.
    if (.not. allocated (v1)) allocate(v1(n,n))    
    
    !$omp parallel
    !$omp do private(i, j, k) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+: v1)    
    do i = 1, n 
      do j = 1, n
        v1(i,j) = c0
        do k = 1, n
          v1(i,j) = v1(i,j) + k
        end do
        write (*,*) i, j, v1(i,j)
      end do
    end do  
    !$omp end do  
    !$omp end parallel

end subroutine
```

the code runs normally.